# Custom user activation methods in sorcery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sorcery

I am using the [sorcery gem](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery) in a Rails 4 application.  I need to configure two attributes that sorcery [says I can configure](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/wiki/User-Activation), however I do not know how to actually configure those values.

The two attributes in question are:

```
activation_needed_email
```

and

```
activation_success_email
```

How can I customize these method names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributes you want to override are `activation_needed_email_method_name` and `activation_success_email_method_name`, as seen here: https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/blob/master/lib/sorcery/model/submodules/user_activation.rb

**Solution**
There are a number of ways to accomplish this.  Something like this should work:

In your `sorcery.config` file:

```
Rails.application.config.sorcery.configure do |config|
  config.user_config do |user|
    user.activation_needed_email_method_name = :whatever_your_method_is
    user.activation_success_email_method_name = :whatever_your_method_is
  end
end
```

**Reference**:  Here is a good gist with example configurations for many (all?) things that are configurable within sorcery:  https://gist.github.com/reqshark/3063261